# Oracle DB query not returning the expecting results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Could you please suggest me how to execute my query to get expected results? Below we can see the actual and expected output results.

```
WITH constants as (
    select  
        '' NA, 
        '1.7' version, 
        'test' needBrand, 
        ' ' needIdNbr, 
        'cox  ' needFirstName, 
        ' ' needMiddleName, 
        'simson' needLastName, 
        ' ' needNameSuffix, 
        '10115 Jeffreys St' needAddrLine1, 
        ' ' needAddrLine2, 
        'Las Vegas' needCity, 
        'NV' needState, 
        '89183' needZipCode, 
        ' ' needCountry,
        '1000047710' needPhoneNbr, 
        'tcc_04@test.com' needEmailAddr, 
        ' ' USAGE
    from dual    
)
SELECT  constants.version AS version,  
     TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi:ss') AS extractDate,  
     constants.needBrand AS needBrand,  
     constants.needIdNbr AS needIdNbr,  
     constants.needFirstName AS needFirstName,  
     constants.needMiddleName AS needMiddleName,  
     constants.needLastName AS needLastName,  
     constants.needNameSuffix AS needNameSuffix,  
     constants.needAddrLine1 AS needAddrLine1,  
     constants.needAddrLine2 AS needAddrLine2,  
     constants.needCity AS needCity,  
     constants.needState AS needState,  
     constants.needZipCode AS needZipCode,  
     constants.needCountry AS needCountry,  
     constants.needPhoneNbr AS needPhoneNbr, 
     constants.needEmailAddr AS needEmailAddr,  
     constants.USAGE AS USAGE, UPPER(user_status) AS Status,
     UPPER(user_type) AS Type,
     TO_CHAR(CREATED,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS Date 
     from usertitle ue,constants
```

**Actual output:**

```
version      needFirstName            Status                   Type 
--------     -------------           ------------             -------- ...etc
  1             David                Cancelled_pending        SHOEBOX 
  1             james                Subscribed_Pending       GiftBox
```

**Expected output:** while running the query we are expecting below results like this. There is no '_' in status and need space in Type column.

```
Version      needFirstName          Status                   Type 
--------     -------------        ------------              -------- ... etc
   1            David             Cancelled pending         SHOE BOX 
   1            james             Subscribed Pending        Gift Box
```

Comment: Where's `usertitle` table? Btw, this question reminds me [which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441727/oracle-db-query-not-returning-the-expecting-output/59442889#59442889) should be a popular homework question nowadays :)

Comment: Why do you expect those results?

Answer (score 0):

Status and Type are coming from "select UPPER(user_status) AS Status, UPPER(user_type) from usertitle " (I removed constants for simplicity). There is no operation happening on these columns which will add space or remove underscore. You need to call a function to those operations on user_status and user_type columns.

You can use REPLACE function to replace "_" with a space and "BOX" with " BOX". This will change all instances of _ and BOX.

For status column you can do as,

```
select REPLACE(UPPER(user_status),'_',' ') AS Status,  REPLACE(UPPER(user_type),'BOX',' BOX') AS Type 
from usertitle;
```

If you want to alter a particular instance of substring then - 
1. You can use INSTR function to find the position of the substring
2. Then use SUBSTR function to split the column at that location into 2 parts. The final string will be `part1 || ' ' || part2` add a space and then

Comment: Still i'm not clear, could you please send the updated query to get expected results

Comment: If it works then you may want to up vote the answer.

Comment: How can i use  INSTR function to replace fine "BOX" and add a space before it.can you explain detail related to above mentioned  query that would be great.

Comment: can you please explain above comment.

Comment: Mani, try the SQL. if it works then upvote the answer.